# Display more than one video from one button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, xcode4.3

From the page where I can select which chapter that I want, after selecting the chapter, it will show the description page. At the navigation bar, there is a Back button and a Video button.

For every different chapter that I select, the video that is being displayed need to be different. But how do i display out 10 different videos from the Video button?

The TableView and the description of the chapter is retrieved from database and the videos are just stored in a folder in Xcode.

Currently, from any chapter that i press the video, the video will just appear the same.
The codes I'm using is this:

```
-(IBAction)playvideo {

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"mp4"]];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
                                                 initWithContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];

playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];

playercontroller = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think in your database should also store the information of the respective video(may be filename) too?

Comment: If i do that, how do i retrieve the correct video depending on which chapter i press?

Comment: When you hit any chapter, you should get the id of the chapter, and retrieve which video needs be displayed from the database.

Comment: I tried, but its not able to display any video if i use the codes above to get the video.

Comment: In your code, you are hardcoding to play 'example.mp4'. You should send the video name as a parameter to the method. Video name of course should come from database and video file should reside locally.